# extract data inside script tag

Tags: elixir, html-parsing

I am new to elixir programming, writing a script to fetch a list of movies from a URL using `httpoison`, which results in raw [html](https://gist.github.com/navyad/cd03bc702ea17623571bb89e183f08a8).

For parsing I am using the [floki](https://github.com/philss/floki), So the list of movies lies inside a javascript [tag](https://gist.github.com/navyad/cd03bc702ea17623571bb89e183f08a8#file-imdb_page-L1036), which is very difficult to parse.

I guess it would be easier if complete DOM tree can be created/loaded and then parse it.

Is there any way to make things easier ?

Answer (score 0):

`IMDbReactInitialState.push({"user":{"id":"...` the argument to the `push` looks like JSON to me.

So, if you have the contents of the script tag, strip it of `IMDbReact...` you can use a package like https://hex.pm/packages/jason to convert it to an Elixir data structure